# Why isn't this cron doing anything?

Tags: cron, rsync

So, I have a very simple cron set up to run daily. It does a find and rsync with certain parameters. When it runs on the bash command line, it runs just fine, but when in the root crontab, it doesn't want to know. Any ideas what is wrong here?

```
/usr/bin/find /var/www/*/logs/ -iname '*.lzma' -mtime +21 -exec rsync -a --ignore-existing --relative -e 'ssh -q -p 2230 -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no"' {} root@nas0:/space/Logs/reporting0/ \;
```

Syslog shows it ran:

```
Apr 28 09:40:01 reporting1 CRON[26347]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/find /var/www/*/logs/ -iname '*.lzma' -mtime +21 -exec rsync -a --ignore-existing --relative -e 'ssh -q -p 2230 -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no"' {} root@nas0:/space/Logs/reporting1/ \;)
```

But nothing actually gets copied.

Answer (score 1):

> Cron always runs with a mostly empty environment. HOME, LOGNAME, and
> SHELL are set; and a very limited PATH.

[link here](https://serverfault.com/a/337921)

So you can  **complete  all application with the full path** or **add the environment variables**.

For example in Ubuntu you can
replace **rsync** by **/usr/bin/rsync**
repalce   **ssh**  by **/usr/bin/ssh**

You can check your cron's environment variable by
add this to cron  and check the /tmp/env.output

```
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output
```

[here is detail](https://askubuntu.com/a/23438/673347)

Comment: I actually did get bitten with an earlier version of this script using a variable that wasn't in use. Sadly in this case, the PATH variable points to the right location and your suggestion to send the envs to a file showed it to be the case. Either way, pre-pending /usr/bin did not help matters unfortunately.

Comment: Since I know this works on the command line, I'm just going to convert it to a script to run daily. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: For posterity, the reason this wasn't working was that the rsync command is trying to connect as root and the root user doesn't actually have a key pair on the source machine. The reason it worked on the command line was because I have key forwarding working. A real facepalm moment, although in my defence, there were NO indications of any errors.